# JRuby frozen objects versus Garbage Collector

Tags: object, garbage-collection, jruby

Could frozen objects in JRuby be the reason for a memory leak? Or does the Garbage Collector destroy frozen objects ?

My problem is that I have an app which has some frozen hashes running around and I did not find out just yet where they are coming from and I would really like to know if frozen objects could throw ActionView::Template::Error (GC overhead limit exceeded) or OutOfMemory Java error or at least contribute to such an error.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

No. All Object#freeze does is call [org::jruby::RubyObject::freeze](http://jruby0.9.sourcearchive.com/documentation/0.9.9-8/classorg_1_1jruby_1_1RubyObject_528b36da4117a663fa4d27b905f461dd.html) which then calls [org::jruby::RubyObject::setFrozen](http://jruby0.9.sourcearchive.com/documentation/0.9.9-8/classorg_1_1jruby_1_1RubyObject_2fbc0132252c5d22a2529bc107932658.html#2fbc0132252c5d22a2529bc107932658) which sets a property on the IRubyObject.

Nothing here would have any effect on GC.